# Fingerprint for using mapview in android

Tags: android, debugging

I'm new in development , trying to use mapview but not able to generate fingerprint
i used

```
C:\Users\SID>keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\SID\.
```

`android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android`

in  command  promt 
but it is giving error **'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.** I'm using WINDOWS 7. kindly guide me,thanx

Answer (score 0):

Add the SDK dir to your PATH environmental variable

Answer (score 0):

i have solved it

C:\j2sdk1.4.2_04\bin>keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\SID
\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android

just finding the keytool location running it with the same query